# Using a proxy with PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser

Tags: php, html, web-scraping, simple-html-dom

I'm having some issues getting [**PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser**](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual_faq.htm) to work with a proxy. I read the info they have on the procedure in the manual but it still isn't cooperating.

```
require_once('simple_html_dom.php');

$url = 'http://www.whatsmyip.org/';
$proxy = '00.000.000.80:80';

$context = array( 
   'http' => array( 
      'proxy' => $proxy,
      'request_fulluri' => true, 
    ), 
);
$context = stream_context_create($context); 

$dom = new simple_html_dom();
$dom = file_get_html($url, false, $context);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($dom);
echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: Ah yes. "not working". Very specific. Have you tried Universal Computer Cure #1: Reboot/restart?

Comment: do you actually have a proxy server at `00.000.000.80:80`? Because that isn't a valid IP.

Comment: @MarcB sorry Mark, it looks to be timing out after a minute.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn, no I just wanted to conceal it for StackOverflow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I only changed some parts, but clearly, the proxy example you provided it isn't working. Try this instead:

```
$context = array('http' => array('proxy' => 'tcp://221.176.14.72:80','request_fulluri' => true,),);
$stream = stream_context_create($context);
$dom = file_get_html('http://www.whatsmyip.org/', false, $stream);
$ip = $dom->find('span#ip', 0)->innertext;
echo $ip;
```

Comment: This worked for me, thank you. The proxies I tried were probably bad come to think of it. I have an alternative solution below that worked as well.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to get it working using cURL to feed the page into PHP Simple HTML dom parser.

```
require_once('simple_html_dom.php');

$url = 'http://www.whatsmyip.org/';
$proxy = '00.000.000.80:80';

$options = array( 
    CURLOPT_PROXY          => $proxy,
    CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL => 0,
    CURLOPT_REFERER        => "http://www.google.com",
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT      => "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.1) Gecko/20061204 Firefox/2.0.0.1", 
    CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 20,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 20,
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS      => 10,
    CURLOPT_HEADER         => true,

); 

$ch = curl_init( $url ); 
curl_setopt_array( $ch, $options ); 
$content = curl_exec( $ch ); 

$dom = new simple_html_dom();
$dom->load($content,true,false);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($dom);
echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: well it's logical to use this as well, since curl is much flexible